# How to trigger a share current location when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone

Tags: html, wordpress, geolocation, href

i need an href to add to link, where it share current user location.
like: 
But to share current location instead of initiating call.

Comment: Are you wanting to use google api or not? What information are you requiring? Longitude/latitude or actual address? Please provide more detailed information - update tour question and comment below when you have done so. Either way it will require permission from the end user before the information can be gathered.

Comment: hello...
i may have either want it to be shown as address or mark on map.

the main reason so you can understand, i want to add this as button on woocommerce checkout page, so client can share location with order to make it easier for my delivery boys.

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to do some research re google maps api and also woocommerce hooks/actions. Stack Exchange isn't the forum to ask such broad questions unfortunately.